# Creating tables and writing to Servlet

Tags: java, servlets, jdbc, odbc

I having trouble creating a table in a database. The code doesn't seem to have any errors yet doesn't output anything. I've tried debugging it and it seems that the problem is either the connection or the statement object, I think...

If any one can help that would be helpful, thanks.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver;

/**
 * @author 
 */
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/FoodServlet"})
public class FoodServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private Connection con;
    private Statement stmt;
    private ResultSet rs;
    private PreparedStatement pstmt;

    //Servlet initialization method creates con/stmt objects and loads jdbc drivers
    @Override
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        try {
            new JdbcOdbcDriver();
            String url = "jdbc:odbc:Food";
            String user = "";
            String password = "";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            stmt = con.createStatement();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     * @throws java.sql.SQLException
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException, SQLException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {

            //delete the database
            stmt.executeUpdate("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Foods");

            //set up the database
            stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE Foods (ItemID Integer PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, ItemName VARCHAR(20), Likes Integer)");
            stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Foods VALUES ('Ice Cream', 0)");
            stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Foods VALUES ('Hamburger', 0)");
            stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Foods VALUES ('Pizza', 0)");

            //set likeValues for data storage
            int likeValue;

            //set strings for queries and update statements
            String query = "SELECT Likes FROM Foods WHERE ItemName = ?";
            String update = "UPDATE Foods SET Likes = ? WHERE ItemName = ?";

            //set food to request parameter from html
            String food = request.getParameter("food");

            //get current likes and increase by one, store in 'likeValue'
            pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
            pstmt.setString(1, food);
            rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
            likeValue = rs.getInt(1) + 1;

            //write updated 'likeValue' to the database
            pstmt = con.prepareStatement(update);
            pstmt.setInt(1, likeValue);
            pstmt.setString(2, food);
            pstmt.executeUpdate();

            //output the data from the database
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT ItemID, ItemName, Likes FROM Foods");
            out.println("ItemID ItemName Likes");
            while (rs.next()) {
                out.print(rs.getInt(1) + "\t\t" + rs.getString(2) + "\t\t"
                        + rs.getInt(3));
            }

        } finally {

        }
    }

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            processRequest(request, response);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FoodServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            processRequest(request, response);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FoodServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

Comment: Why setting up db in request processing method?

Comment: its how I learned from my prof. Also, netbeans auto-creats the process request so that it doesn't matter if the form data is sent using GET or POST.

Comment: This code won't compile - the try block must have catch or finally clause

Comment: I tried adding the catch (SQLException e) with no luck. The Finally Statement did not help either

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? And why are you using the ODBC bridge which is buggy and slow (and is no longer available in Java8).

Comment: I'm using MS access with ODBC. It's part of my school work, I have no control over which dbms I can use. I would rather use MySQL. I think I may have solved my issue and will post it when it's ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after much work I found that the connection object was the first issue, which I'm not sure how I fixed it... I then had an issue with null pointer exceptions which I solved by placing my exceuteUpdate() into an if statement which checked for a value from the html page. I then had an error which involved not having the correct spelling with one of my table values.

This is the updated code which now works, it's not pretty but it works. Thank you everyone for the help!

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import sun.jdbc.odbc.*;

/**
 *
 * @author 
 */
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/FoodServlet"})
public class FoodServlet extends HttpServlet {

    private Connection con;
    private Statement stmt;
    private ResultSet rs;
    private PreparedStatement pstmt;
    private DatabaseMetaData dbmd;

    //Servlet initialization method creates con/stmt objects and loads jdbc drivers
    public void init() throws ServletException {
        try {
            new JdbcOdbcDriver();
            String url = "jdbc:odbc:Java3DB";
            String user = "";
            String pword = "";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, pword);
            stmt = con.createStatement();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code>
     * methods.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     * @throws java.sql.SQLException
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException, SQLException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            //open html tags
            out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>FoodServlet</title>");
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");

            //set up the table
            createTable();

            //set strings for queries and update statements
            String update = "UPDATE Foods SET likes = (likes + 1) WHERE itemName = ?";

            //set foodValue to request parameter from html
            String foodValue = null;
            foodValue = request.getParameter("food");
            //update only if there is a value stored in the food parameter
            if (foodValue != null) {
                //out.println(foodValue);
                pstmt = con.prepareStatement(update);
                pstmt.setString(1, foodValue);
                pstmt.executeUpdate();
            }

            //output the data from the database
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT itemID, itemName, likes FROM Foods");
            out.println("ItemID&nbsp&nbspItemName&nbsp&nbspLikes <BR>");

            while (rs.next()) {
                out.print(+rs.getInt(1) + "&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp" 
                        + rs.getString(2) + "&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp" 
                        + rs.getInt(3) + "<br>");
            }

            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            out.print(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    //destroy method to close the servlet
    public void destroy() {
        try {
            stmt.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FoodServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public void createTable() throws SQLException {
        dbmd = con.getMetaData();
        rs = dbmd.getTypeInfo();
        //checks for the Foods table, create only if not table is found
        if (rs.next() == false) {
            //set up the database
            stmt.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE Foods (itemID INTEGER, itemName VARCHAR(20), likes Integer)");
            stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Foods VALUES (1, 'IceCream', 0)");
            stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Foods VALUES (2, 'Hamburger', 0)");
            stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Foods VALUES (3, 'Pizza', 0)");
        }
    }

// <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            processRequest(request, response);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FoodServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     *
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        try {
            processRequest(request, response);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(FoodServlet.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     *
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see you have used the same Statement (stmt) in couple of places and that is not a good practice.
Use one statement for each query you execute and close it properly inside the finally{} block to avoid connection/resource issues.

I also suspect that your queries doesn't have selected any database. it just uses "foo" table but where does it located (database)? shouldn't it be "databaseName.foo" ..?

use proper try/catch/finally structure and close all your used statements, resultSets and connection inside it.

follow above steps and let us know your issue still exists or any exception you get.

Comment: I've tried closing all statements but it help the situation. I have noticed that if I use this program to create a table in a database I've used in other programs it also does not work. I've compared my code to my previous work and came up with no differences...

Comment: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Number of query values and destination fields are not the same.
I got this to print from the stacktrace. Not sure if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle doc mentions very clearly, do not call  `System.exit` in servlet `init()` method. So, please comment it out.

And you are specifying Table-Name in url `jdbc:odbc:Foods` , and Foods is your table name. It should be `jdbc:odbc:DATABSE_NAME` . So `init()` throws an exception, as it is not able to find the database *Foods* , it goes to catch block and it encounters  `System.exit` . It prevents the servlet from loading. That's why you are not able to see any error. Because servlet did not even load. As `init()` is not throwing `ServletException` OR `UnavailableException`. Then definitely exception is `SQLException` which gets handled by catch block.

Sorry for the mistake. I have kept the mistake as it is, or it will make your comment irrelevant.

My current observation says that you have forgotten to call `rs.next()` after
`rs = pstmt.executeQuery();` . Which throws Exception because `RESULTSET` pointer is not properly placed. Try calling `rs.next()` .

Another wrong practice in your code is that , you have not used  `catch(){}` after try block. If you use it, you should print the exception, it should not be blank. That is the reason you did not get any trace of the exception. Even your `finally{}` is empty. Either do not use `catch(){}` or when you use it, print something informational.

Comment: Commenting out system.exit didn't help. The database name is Food while the table name is Foods, so this should not be a cause for error. Also, The servlet does load, but it loads a blank page since the code is not retrieving data from the database as there is no table.

Comment: @GrizzlySol you can check my answer now. I think you missed rs.next() .

Comment: I've recently tried using both catch and finally statements with no change in my result. Also, I am using rs.next() in my while loop.
It seems to be a problem with updating the database, it should be in an if statement. I will update soon.

Comment: @GrizzlySol I was talking about this part `rs = pstmt.executeQuery(); likeValue = rs.getInt(1) + 1;` ... You were missing `rs.next()` after it.